# python deleting directly reoccurring values from list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have written a code in javascript that I don't know how to write in python. The use of it is rather simple. There are 2 variables: Buy and Sell. E.g There is Buy, Buy, Sell, Buy, Sell, Sell
the javascript gives me a new list with Buy,Sell,Buy,Sell

```
´´const fs = require('fs');

class Trade {
 price;
side;
}

const array = 

console.log('AllTrades:');
console.log(array);

let trades = [];

for(let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
let trade = array[i];
let nextTrade = array[i - 1];



if(nextTrade) {
if(trade[0] == "BUY" && nextTrade[0] == "SELL") {
    trades[i] = trade;
}
if(trade[0] == "SELL" && nextTrade[0] == "BUY") {
    trades[i] = trade;
}
} else if(trade[0] == "BUY") {
trades[i] = trade;
}
}

trades = trades.filter(function (i) { return i != undefined;});

console.log('D Trades:');
for(let i = 0; i < trades.length; i++) {
console.log(trades[i]);
}

fs.writeFile('./data/trades.json', JSON.stringify(trades), (err, data) => {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
console.log('Trades > trades.txt');
});  ´´
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby` can handle this.  It works sort of like `uniq` on the command line in that it groups runs of equal values (by whatever key you provide).

```
from itertools import groupby

trades = ["Buy", "Buy", "Sell", "Buy", "Sell", "Sell"]
deduped_trades = [g for g, _ in groupby(trades)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume seeig your question that you are not familiar with python, here is my solution:

```
list= ["Sell","Sell","Buy","Sell","Sell","Buy","Buy","Buy","Sell","Sell","Buy","Buy","Sell","Sell"];
index=[];

for k in range(len(list)-1):
    if list[k]==list[k+1]:
        index.append(k);
print (index)
for k in range(len(index)):
    list.pop(index[k]);
    if k<len(index)-1:
         index[k+1]=index[k+1]-(k+1);
    

 print (index);
 print(list);
```

I've chosen to use 2 loop because if you pop an element of a list in the first loop you are gooing to have a range error since the list now have len(list)-1 string. I just used append function to add element at the end of a list, and pop to erase an element by giving index

The first loop create a list with all the index of duplicate string, the second erase them

Comment: thanks, i see the logic behind it tho it doesn't work. I think because the list has 2 columns e.g ["BUY", 3.156], ["BUY", 3.234],... and therefore the index list stays empty and the list list is just the list as original